# SumIF column a = X AND column b = Y OR Z

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula

I'm struggling to create a formula which sums Column C IF (Column A = [name]) AND (Column B = "Possible" OR "Proposed" OR "Committed").

Answer (score 1):

Use SumProduct with + as the or operator rather than * as the and operator. Something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A:$A=[name])*(($B:$B="Proposed")+($B:$B="Possible")+($B:$B="Committed"))*($C:$C))
```

Comment: Unless the OP actually has data extending all the way to row 1048576, the use of entire column references within SUMPRODUCT is a terrible idea.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(($A1:$A100=[name])*(($B1:$B100="Proposed")+($B1:$B100="Possible")+($B1:$B100="Committed"))*($C1:$C100)) Happy?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=[name])*(((B:B="Possible")+(B:B="Proposed")+(B:B="Committed"))>0),C:C)
```

Comment: Unless the OP actually has data extending all the way to row 1048576, the use of entire column references within SUMPRODUCT is a terrible idea.

Comment: Agreed. Hope OP would limit the row based on the actual number of rows from this base formula.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,[name],$B:$B,{"Proposed","Possible","Committed"}))`

With some functions, e.g. `COUNTIF`, `SUMIF`, `COUNTIFS`, `SUMIFS`, you can get away with referencing entire columns with no detriment to performance, though not with functions which operate over arrays, such as `AGGREGATE`, `SUMPRODUCT`, and any construction requiring `CSE`.

Regards